flutter get_it does not generate file as expected
I am using get_it to manage dependencies but recently I find the generated file has some issue.
I have three implementations of LogOutput for different environments. However, FirebaseLogOutput and ConsoleLogOutput are below the LoggerService. As a result, when I run my app in development environment, I got LogOutput not registered in get_it error.
Not sure if there is idea what could be wrong? Thank you
gh.factory<_i9.LogOutput>(
      () => _i10.NoLogOutput(),
      registerFor: {_integrationTest},
    );
    gh.singleton<_i9.Logger>(
        () => _i11.LoggerService(logOutput: gh<_i9.LogOutput>()));
    gh.factory<_i9.LogOutput>(
      () => _i12.FirebaseLogOutput(),
      registerFor: {
        _alpha,
        _beta,
        _production,
      },
    );
...
    gh.factory<_i9.LogOutput>(
      () => _i30.ConsoleLogOutput(),
      registerFor: {_development},
    );

